# Naive Bayes in R, Sentiment analysis leads to cannot coerce class error

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataframe `df_tweets` that has two columns `tweets` and `score`.
Score is a factor with values between `1 to 5`

```
getMatrix <- function(chrVect){
 testsource <- VectorSource(chrVect)
 testcorpus <- Corpus(testsource)
 testcorpus <- tm_map(testcorpus,stripWhitespace)
 testcorpus <- tm_map(testcorpus, removeWords, stopwords('french'))
 testcorpus <- tm_map(testcorpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
 testcorpus <- tm_map(testcorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
 testcorpus <- tm_map(testcorpus, removePunctuation)
 testcorpus <- tm_map(testcorpus, removeNumbers)
 testcorpus <- tm_map(testcorpus, PlainTextDocument)

 return(DocumentTermMatrix(testcorpus))
}

op =getMatrix(df_tweets$text)
classifier <-naiveBayes(as.matrix(op), as.factor(df_tweets$avg_score))
```

When I use the predict function I get an error

```
myPrediction<- predict(classifier,op)

Error in as.data.frame.default(newdata) : 
cannot coerce class "c("DocumentTermMatrix", "simple_triplet_matrix")" to a data.frame
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Maybe wrap `as.matrix` with `as.data.frame` or directly with `as.matrix.data.frame`???

Comment: That worked. If you can post that as an answer I can accept it / Or Delete my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can wrap `as.matrix` with `as.data.frame` or directly with `as.matrix.data.frame`.